# Find duplicate strings in a large file

Tags: algorithm, string

A file contains a large number (eg.10 billion) of strings and you need to find duplicate Strings. You have N number of systems available. How will you find duplicates

Comment: Is this homework?  This sounds like homework.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split the file into N pieces. On each machine, load as much of the piece into memory as you can, and sort the strings. Write these chunks to mass storage on that machine. On each machine, merge the chunks into a single stream, and then merge the stream from each machine into a stream that contains all of the strings in sorted order. Compare each string with the previous. If they are the same, it is a duplicate.

Comment: To merge the chunks into single stream, you would have to load all records in memory. For a 1 mil record file, all the 1 mil records would have to be in memory at the last merge step in the above algorithm right? If yes, then that defeats the purpose.

Comment: @AndyDufresne "To merge the chunks into single stream, you would have to load all records in memory." No, you wouldn't. You only need enough memory to load the next string from each chunk at once, in order to compare them. Once the comparison has been performed, the next string will occupy that memory space.

Comment: I didn't understand your merge algorithm. Say we have 1 mil record file and only 5k records can be loaded in the memory. From what I understood, I need to first split the file in N pieces with 5K records each. Then sort all the records in each 5k records files and write back. To merge two 5k record files, I would have to load 10k records in memory right?

If this is not what you meant, can you explain the steps to find duplicate records in a 1 mil record file with the memory limit of loading just 5k records.

Comment: @AndyDufresne [This article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/External_sorting) explains the general concept better than I probably can in a comment. If you have specific questions about how to apply it here, I will try to address them.

Answer (score 8):

erickson's answer is probably the one expected by whoever set this question.

You could use each of the N machines as a bucket in a hashtable:

- for each string, (say string number i in sequence) compute a hash function on it, h.
- send the the values of i and h to machine number n for storage, where n = h % N.
- from each machine, retrieve a list of all hash values h for which more than one index was received, together with the list of indexes.
- check the sets of strings with equal hash values, to see whether they're actually equal.

To be honest, though, for 10 billion strings you could plausibly do this on 1 PC. The hashtable might occupy something like 80-120 GB with a 32 bit hash, depending on exact hashtable implementation. If you're looking for an efficient solution, you have to be a bit more specific what you mean by "machine", because it depends how much storage each one has, and the relative cost of network communication.